# How can cache times be controlled in Site.com?

Tags: performance, site.com

According to the [Site.com informational page](http://www.site.com/features#row04)

> Site.com leverages a global network of caching servers that deliver
>   content with fewer server hops

1. How can I (or can I at all) set cache times for pages in Site.com?  I know that [apex:page](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_page.htm) has cache="true" and expires="numberOfSeconds", which defaults to 600, when cache="true".
2. Can data retrievals be cached?  The Salesforce Help Page: [Improving Performance Using Caching](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=siteforce_data_caching.htm&language=en_US) under the Dynamically Retrieving and Displaying Section states that there is a property for it (see quote below), but I cannot find it on a data repeater or page.  What element is it a property of?

> The Cache Duration (Minutes) field in the Properties tab controls the
>   length of time to cache retrieved data for the selected data repeater,
>   data table, or data function.

Ideally, these things could be set through the Site.com UI; however, a custom code block (i.e., plain old HTML and/or JavaScript) solution would be a last resort acceptable solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a feature in the next salesforce release ([Spring 13](https://na1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_spring13_release_notes.pdf)), which is tentatively scheduled for next weekend. Since salesforce staggers releases across different clusters, this would explain why some organizations see the feature and others don't. The release documentation is not staggered, which explains why you are able to read about features in a future release.

The feature itself is pretty straightforward, it's the number of minutes you want the data query to be cached (so it doesn't make a full API request and slow down your site).

It is located in a new section of the properties called **Cache**.

[image]

This field appears to be visible on the following data components:

- Data Function
- Data Table
- Data Repeater

Comment: Awesome!!! Do you know if there is any such feature to cache at the page level like there is on the [apex:page's cache attribute](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_page.htm)?

Comment: Awesome! Great answer!

Comment: No way to do it for pages that I know of. In my experience, the slowest part of the pages are usually the data components, so by caching them you're already getting most of the performance improvement that you would get by caching the entire page.

Comment: Will this be available after our org goes to Spring 13. What does this mean? "Available for purchase in: Enterprise and Unlimited Editions". Thanks.